# single variable is significant but overall test is not

Tags: statistics, regression, statistical-inference, regression-analysis

I do a multiple regression with 3 independent variables $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$. The correlation between $Y$ and $X_1$, $Y$ and $X_2$, and $Y$ and $X_3$, are each large and statistically significant. When I fit the multiple regression, none of the t-tests on individual coefficients are significant. How could this happen?

Comment: More likely the 'opposite': $X_1, X_2,$ and $X_3$ contain essentially the same information (roughly co-linearity) and none stands out above the others in the multiple regression. I suppose the overall model in the latter case is significant. Insufficient information to answer for sure.

Comment: This surely suggests multicollinearity problem exists.

Comment: Can you post the full regression output?

Comment: @MerylStreep. This is an question from qualifying exam. And the above is the whole question.

Comment: Then I agree with @Seow Fan Chong. This looks like a question on imperfect multicollinearity -- what you are describing is possible if variables are highly intercorrelated.

Comment: Your title of the question is a bit misleading -- the test for the overall significance of the regression is the F-test but the problem itself says nothing about the values of the F-statistic.

Comment: I also agree with @SeowFanChong and MertkStreep....collinearity inflates the standard errors of your coefficients, so none seem significantly different from zero.